# How to get object from nested object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to return the object based on `country_name` in input object using javascript.
Input object as `sampleobj` and  variable `source`, passed as parameters to the function which in turn should return a output obj based on `source` using javascript,

I have tried this below

```
var source="TH";
var result = filterData(sampleobj, source);
function filterData(inputobj, src){
var filterByCountry = inputobj.filter((e)=>e.country_from.country.includes(src));
return filterByCountry;
}
```

```
var sampleobj = [
   {
     id: "trans",
     country_from: [
       {
         country: "SG"
         currency: ["SGD", "USD"]
       },
       {
         country: "TH"
         currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       }

     ]
   },
    {
     id: "fund",
     country_from: [
       {
         country: "TH"
         currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       },
       {
         country: "UK"
         currency: ["GBP", "USD"]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
result =[{
     id: "trans",
     country_from: [
       {
         country: "TH"
         currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       }
     ]
},
{
     id: "fund",
     country_from: [
       {
         country: "TH"
         currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       }
     ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

With filter we take out only matching `country` and place it back as `country_from's` value

```js
let sampleobj = [{id: "trans",country_from: [{country: "SG",currency: ["SGD", "USD"]},{country: "TH",currency: ["THB", "USD"]}]},
{id: "fund",country_from: [{country: "TH",currency: ["THB", "USD"]},{country: "UK",currency: ["GBP", "USD"]}]}]

const source = 'TH'

const op = sampleobj.map(inp=>{
  const country_from = inp.country_from.filter(({country})=> country === source)
  return {
    ...inp,
    country_from
  }  
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cna use combination of `map` & `filter`. The map will return a new array and inside the map callback function create and return a object with keys `id` and `country_from`. While populating the value of  `country_from` use `filter` to extract only those objects where country is 'TH'

```js
var sampleobj = [{
    id: "trans",
    country_from: [{
        country: "SG",
        currency: ["SGD", "USD"]
      },
      {
        country: "TH",
        currency: ["THB", "USD"]
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    id: "fund",
    country_from: [{
        country: "TH",
        currency: ["THB", "USD"]
      },
      {
        country: "UK",
        currency: ["GBP", "USD"]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let result = sampleobj.map(function(item) {

  return {
    id: item.id,
    country_from: item.country_from.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.country === 'TH'
    })
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array and use `filter` to filter the  `country_from`

```js
var sampleobj = [{"id":"trans","country_from":[{"country":"SG","currency":["SGD","USD"]},{"country":"TH","currency":["THB","USD"]}]},{"id":"fund","country_from":[{"country":"TH","currency":["THB","USD"]},{"country":"UK","currency":["GBP","USD"]}]}];

var source = "TH";
let result = sampleobj.map(({id,country_from}) =>  ({id,country_from: country_from.filter(o => o.country === source)}));

console.log(result);
```

You can add another `filter()` to only return the object with `country_from`

```js
var sampleobj = [{
    "id": "trans",
    "country_from": [{
      "country": "SG",
      "currency": ["SGD", "USD"]
    }, {
      "country": "TH",
      "currency": ["THB", "USD"]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "fund",           //Will not be returned since no TH on country_from
    "country_from": [{
      "country": "ID",
      "currency": ["THB", "USD"]
    }, {
      "country": "UK",
      "currency": ["GBP", "USD"]
    }]
  } 
]

var source = "TH";
let result = sampleobj.map(({id,country_from}) => ({id,country_from: country_from.filter(o => o.country === source)}))
  .filter(o => o.country_from.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Map & Filter and change the Function as follows:

```js
function filterData(inputobj, src) {
        var filterByCountry = inputobj.map(({
            id, country_from
        }) => ({
            id, country_from: country_from.filter(obj => obj.country.includes(src))
        }));
        return filterByCountry;
    }
     var sampleobj = [
            {
                id: "trans"
                , country_from: [
                    {
                        country: "SG"
                        , currency: ["SGD", "USD"]
       }
                    , {
                        country: "TH"
                        , currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       }

     ]
   }
            , {
                id: "fund"
                , country_from: [
                    {
                        country: "TH"
                        , currency: ["THB", "USD"]
       }
                    , {
                        country: "UK"
                        , currency: ["GBP", "USD"]
       }
     ]
   }
]
        var source = "TH";
        var result = filterData(sampleobj, source);
        console.log(result)
```